# MVC - JQuery Datepicker to display events

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui

I'm currently building an MVC application and using a JQuery UI Datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

to book events.

I would like to display all available eventdates in the Datepicker. Is there any way to rerender the datepicker to make only eventdates being selectable(clickable) or may be just highlight the eventdates. Any way to pass dates into the datepicker? Any experience of that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the `beforeShowDay` event of the DatePicker control http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay . It seems ready made for what you are trying to do, you just have to supply a list of dates and the styles to go with it: something like:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { 
        for(i = 0; i < arrayOfCalendarEventDatesYouProvide.length; i++) {
            if(date.getMonth() == arrayOfCalendarEventDatesYouProvide[i].getMonth()
            && date.getDay() == arrayOfCalendarEventDatesYouProvide[i].getDay()
            && date.getYear() == arrayOfCalendarEventDatesYouProvide[i].getYear())

            //matched a day in the array, turn of date in calendar if you
            //don't want it pickable
            return [false, 'some-css-to-indicate-a-match'];
        }

        //if you get this far, no matches
        return [true, ''];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The control offers min-date and max-date, but doesn't support supplying specific dates:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

You'd probably have to modify the control yourself to take in an array of acceptable dates, which might not be that difficult as it seems as you could use the min/max functionality as a starting point.

It's quite an obvious feature missing from the control though!